# OS X - Why does Firefox know my search query in other programs?

Tags: macos, firefox, sublime-text-2

Environment: OS X Yosemite 10.10.3, Sublime Text 2.0.2, Pages 5.5.3, Firefox 38.0.5

Observation: When I find a word in Sublime Text 2 / Pages, and switch to Firefox, wanting to search the same word on page, I notice that the search box is automatically filled with that word, without needing to use clipboard.
I can confirm that I didn't accidentally press  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>  or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>  .
This also works the other way, but Sublime Text 2 / Pages only knows a part of the word.

I'm guessing this is a system-level behavior. Just why is this? And why do other program don't know the full word?

Answer (score 0):

OS X actually has 2 copy buffers [I think inherited from [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs), but don't quote me on that]

The regular Copy & Paste everybody knows -  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>  &  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>

Then there's Kill & Yank - called by  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd>  &  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Y</kbd>

The search in many apps uses this second kill/yank buffer, so opening a new search will often auto-fill from there - but it is not infallible, nor fully ubiquitous. Some apps will fill from the regular copy buffer if kill is empty.